# WooCommerce progress bar from cart contents total value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, woocommerce, progress-bar

My aiming result is like this:
[image]

With the current code its not showing the cart total in the progress bar. What am I doing wrong?
And how can I integrate those steps/stacks?

```js
var carttotal = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total(); 
document.getElementById("cart-progress-bar").value = carttotal;
```

```css
#cart-progress-bar {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
  box-sizing: initial;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  border:1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<progress id="cart-progress-bar" max="100" value="0"></progress>
```

Comment: I tried your code with demo number for `carttotal` it was not showing the total on progress bar . Then i have removed `width: auto;` from your css and it works .Remove and see onces if that works

Comment: its not setting any value on my end unfortunatly, Ive checked with several cart values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example didn't state exactly where you wanted this. I've added it to the cart page via the `woocommerce_before_cart_table` action hook. Which would look like this after adding some extra CSS styling.

[image]

You could also add this to a template file of course without the `add_action`/`function` mark up.

Action hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_table', 'cart_discount_progress_bar' );
function cart_discount_progress_bar() {

    // Create progress bar
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total() + WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_tax();
    printf( '<progress id="cart-progress-bar" max="100" value="%s"></progress>', $cart_total );

    // Create steps
    $steps = array(
        0 => '',
        30 => __( '3% discount', 'discount-bar'), 
        50 => __( '8% discount', 'discount-bar'), 
        100 => __( '10% discount', 'discount-bar'), 
    );
    echo '<div id="cart-progress-steps">';
    foreach ( $steps as $step => $discount ) {
        printf('<div class="step step-%1$s" style="left:%1$s%%">%2$s<span class="discount">%3$s</span></div>', $step, wc_price( $step ), $discount );
    }
    echo '</div>';

}
```

CSS:

```
.woocommerce-cart #cart-progress-bar {
    border-radius:0;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    margin-top: 1em;
    color: cornflowerblue;
    background: floralwhite;
}

.woocommerce-cart #cart-progress-bar::-webkit-progress-value {
    background: cornflowerblue;
}

.woocommerce-cart #cart-progress-bar::-webkit-progress-bar {
    background: floralwhite;
}

.woocommerce-cart #cart-progress-steps {
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}

.woocommerce-cart #cart-progress-bar,
.woocommerce-cart #cart-progress-steps {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.woocommerce-cart #cart-progress-steps .step {
    position: absolute;
    width: 70px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.woocommerce-cart #cart-progress-steps .step .discount {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 11px;
    display: block;
}

.woocommerce-cart #cart-progress-steps .step:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 18px;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    left: 50%;
    top: -26px;
}
```

The mistake in your example was that you were trying to use PHP to create a value for a JavaScript variable. So to make that work you would either have to jump in and out of PHP:

```
var carttotal = <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total() + WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_tax(); ?>;
```

Or choose to build your whole progress bar in PHP like in my example.

Comment: awesome, thank you very much! May I ask you how I can change the steps with this function so its showing for example "3% discount for 30€ Cart-total" and next step "5% discount for 50€ cart total"?

Comment: No problem. You can expand the `$steps` array to include discounts. See my updated answer.

Comment: If my last update made this the answer you were looking for I wouldn't mind that bounty. :)

Comment: I accidentally gave @LoicTheAztec the bounty as it was scrolling to him after clicking on the inbox notification of your answer. Is there any way I can correct this or give a bounty manually to you?

Comment: That's unfortunate. I believe once a bounty has been awarded there is no way to move it to a different answer ([Bounty awarded by mistake](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140290/bounty-awarded-to-a-different-answer-by-mistake)). So you would have to create a new bounty, or @LoicTheAztec would have to place a bounty on this question and award it to this answer.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Would you be so kind to place a bounty of +100 onto this question and then award it to the accepted answer? As the bounty was mistakenly awarded to your answer. Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

The main mistake is in your Javascript code in the first line:

```
var carttotal = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();
```

which should be instead:

```
var carttotal = <?php echo (float) WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total(); ?>;
```

And also CSS `width` that needs to be `100%`.

So the code will be *(using jQuery and changed `width` property to `100%`)*:

```
?>
<style>
#cart-progress-bar {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
  box-sizing: initial;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  border:1px solid grey;
}
</style>

<progress id="cart-progress-bar" max="100" value="0"></progress>

<script>
    (function($){
        $('#cart-progress-bar').val(<?php echo floatval( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total() ); ?>);
    })(jQuery);
</script>
<?php
```

Comment: Could you please reply to the comments in the accepted answer above? I've tried numerous ways to contact you about the mistakenly awarded bounty without any luck. I'm hoping you're willing to set this straight. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's quite disappointing to notice you are unwilling to respond to any of my attempts to reach out and set this issue straight. I can clearly see you are active on SO but you won't take the time to address this. Right now it's not even about the reputation points anymore, it's a matter of principle. I thought SO was a fair and supportive community. At this point unfortunately, you make me doubt that.